# fix footer image in tcpdf

Tags: yii, tcpdf

```
 $path = Yii::app()->basePath;
            require_once($path . '/extensions/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
            $pdf = new TCPDF();
            $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
            $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.1);
            $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20, true);
           $footer_image_file = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/logo.jpg';
           $content = '<div> $content </div>'; 
            $pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');
            ob_end_clean();
            $pdf->Output("Reports.pdf", "D");
```

I want to add image in fooder for every new  pages.. please anyone help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put the code displaying the image within the Footer() base method. This base method is called for any new page by either the AddPage() method and Close(). 
Important : The Footer method should not be called directly.

This method is supposed to be implemented in your class, so override it like this :

```
function Footer()
{ 
   .... /* Put your code here (see a working example below) */

   $logoX = 186; // 186mm. The logo will be displayed on the right side close to the border of the page
   $logoFileName = "/images/myLogo.jpg";
   $logoWidth = 15; // 15mm
   $logo = $this->PageNo() . ' | '. $this->Image($logoFileName, $logoX, $this->GetY()+2, $logoWidth);

   $this->SetX($this->w - $this->documentRightMargin - $logoWidth); // documentRightMargin = 18
   $this->Cell(10,10, $logo, 0, 0, 'R');
}
```

I hope this helps and I've well understood your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)))))) The logo displayed on the right side close to the border of the page.. i changed $logoX = 40; $logoWidth = 130; $pdf->Footer(true); Now its showing perfectly....Thank you very much:-))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: But it is not fixed in footer :((((((

Comment: Glad it helped. Indeed you have to adapt the variables based on your image. My image is our company logo but a tiny version to put beside the pageNumber.

Comment: What do you mean by : "But it is not fixed in footer :(((((( " ?

Comment: I see in your comment that your code mentions: `$pdf->Footer(true);`. Be aware that, as said in my post above, it's NOT recommended by the author to be called directly. See [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/footer.htm)

Comment: yaa...sry for that..now i remove this($pdf->Footer(true);). now its working fine.. thanks a lot:-))))

Comment: But it is not fixed in footer :((((((  it means, it was not fixed in footer of all pages...

Answer (score 1):

```
function Footer()
{ 
   .... /* Put your code here (see a working example below) */

   $logoX = 40; // 
   $logoFileName = "/images/myLogo.jpg";
   $logoWidth = 130; // 15mm
   $logoY = 280;
   $logo = $this->PageNo() . ' | '. $this->Image($logoFileName, $logoX, $logoY, $logoWidth);

   $this->SetX($this->w - $this->documentRightMargin - $logoWidth); // documentRightMargin = 18
   $this->Cell(10,10, $logo, 0, 0, 'C');
}
```

This codes are perfectly placed a image in the center of page footer.Thanks a lot pti_jul.:-)))))